# Can I build an unique binary search tree with a valid post order traversal sequence?

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

As the title says, or in other words, is binary search tree and its postorder traversal sequence an one v one model? Is it possible to build two different BST with one postorder traversal sequence?

The original problem is actually a Leetcode problem : "giving a postorder sequence and verify whether it's an valid postorder sequence of a BST.

One none-recursive solution is to traverse the sequence reversely and maintains an increasing stack:

```cpp
class Solution {
public:
    bool verifyPostorder(vector<int>& p) {
        int root = INT_MAX, n = p.size();
        if (!n) return true;

        stack<int> stk;
        stk.push(p[n - 1]);
        for (int i = p.size() - 2; i >= 0; i--) {
            int now = p[i];
            if (now > root) return false;
            while (stk.size() && stk.top() > now) {
                root = stk.top();
                stk.pop();
            }
            stk.push(now);
        }
        return true;
    }
};
```

Using the same logic, I think it will be possible to build a BST from a postorder sequence, for example : `132`, we can build:

```
    2
1       3
```

Comment: Have you tried to build at least a small example where it works?

Comment: well, i have already edit my question, you can see a little example above

Comment: I cannot find the original leetcode problem, but here is a simular one, whichi is verify preorder sequence in bst :
https://leetcode.com/problems/verify-preorder-sequence-in-binary-search-tree
But it needs a premium account to check, i am not sure whether you can see it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i got it. Since we can build a unique binary tree with preorder+inorder or postorder+inorder, and the inorder of a bst is a sorted sequence, therefore if we have a postorder sequence of bst, then we can also get it's inorder sequence by sorting postorder sequence, then we can definitely get an unique bst.